# Требуется ли точка после цифры 8, как символ окончания предложения?

Tags: пунктуация

Название документа должно быть прописано с заглавной буквы, допустимо ли использовать тире перед ссылкой и требуется ли точка после цифры 8, как символ окончания предложения?

Пример правильного запроса приведен в документе "Выдержка из технической спецификации"-https://xn-- стр.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точка в конце нужна, а также нужен пробел после *стр.*